# Array to string conversion in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

I have cloned a Laravel 5.1 project from Git and setup all things as required.

Now I am trying to run any command Like

```
php artisan key:generate
```

or

```
php artisan migrate
```

I am getting following error.

```
Array to string conversion
```

Image:

[image]

Error log from storage/logs:

```
  production.ERROR: ErrorException: Array to 
  string conversion in /var/www/html/codepad/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:67
```

Stack trace:

[image]

I search much about it, but could not get fixed. What could be the issue in this?

Comment: Try to go to storage/logs/laravel.log. The top line should give you more information for when and how the error occurred. Update the question with the error information from there and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: i have updated the question please check

Comment: Can you please go to your routes file (routes.php I believe in 5.1) and show me the line where you have defined post request for uri `/preview` ?

Comment: I fixed this error ,it was due to env file has some param wrongly define. but again getting another issue once run webssite it says 404. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Comment: /var/www/html/codepad/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(750): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: I realy don't know whats going on here.can you please help in this

Comment: try to do composer update

Comment: The 404 error means that you are trying to access an undefined route, for example, it could be that you are trying to make a get request to a route that is defined as a port request.

Comment: How do I know which route is undefined or missing, its not giving any error a well.